# rake -T cannot show my tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

Rakefile:

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "workers/access_token_worker"
require 'dotenv'

Dotenv.load

task :default => 'access_token:refresh'

namespace :access_token do
  task :refresh do
    AccessTokenWorker.work(ENV['WECHAT_APP_ID'], ENV['WECHAT_APP_SECRET'])
  end
end
```

rake -T:

```
rake build          # Build wechat-0.1.0.gem into the pkg directory
rake install        # Build and install wechat-0.1.0.gem into system gems
rake install:local  # Build and install wechat-0.1.0.gem into system gems without network access
rake release        # Create tag v0.1.0 and build and push wechat-0.1.0.gem to Rubygems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not coming as you didn't use any descriptions. Add a description using `desc` like below :

```
$ cat Rakefile
namespace :access_token do
  desc "some tasks"
  task :refresh do
  end
end
$ rake -T
rake access_token:refresh  # some tasks
```

Now, if I remove the `desc`, it wouldn't come. See again :

```
$ cat Rakefile
namespace :access_token do
  task :refresh do
  end
end
$ rake -T
$ rake -P
rake access_token:refresh
```

But, `rake -P` will list even if you don't have `desc` added.

`-P`, `--prereqs` -> Display the tasks and dependencies, then exit.

`-T`, `--task`s `[PATTERN]` -> Display the tasks (matching optional `PATTERN`) with descriptions, then exit.

Comment: Hi, that's the point. But `rake -A` shows nothing, is there anything wrong?

Comment: @goofansu Read the helps using `rake -h`.. `-A, --all` -  Show all tasks, even uncommented ones (in combination with -T or -D)

Comment: `rake -h` says `-A, --all    Show all tasks, even uncommented ones`, but I got nothing.

Comment: @goofansu note _in combination with -T or -D)_ .

Comment: @goofansu Now you know why `-T` didn't list, so write your rake task, and get the targeted task done.. :)